# Codeigniter: Not getting second time result on console, Ajax is not failing though

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I'm working on problem similar to select: **Country->state->city**(through ajax) in Codeigniter where i want to load **Series->season_num->episodes** in a drop down, Using ajax i'm getting result of **season_num** on selecting **series** but my ajax or query (don't know which) is not running right i'm getting empty record while it return the data to ajax as **success**, i'm trying to print the result of query but it's not even printing it in console.
Here is my Ajax function:

```
<script>
 function selectSeasons(series_id)
  {
  // alert(series_id);
   if(series_id != "-1")
   {
     loadData('season',series_id);
     $("#city_dropdown").html("<option value='-1'>Select Episode</option>");  
   }

   else
   {
    $("#season_dropdown").html("<option value='-1'>Select Season Num</option>");
    $("#episode_dropdown").html("<option value='-1'>Select Episode</option>");    
    }
   }

function selectEpisodes(season_id)
 {
  if(season_id != "-1"){
  loadData('episode',season_id);
 }
 else
 {
  $("#episode_dropdown").html("<option value='-1'>Select Episode</option>");    
 }
}

function loadData(loadType,loadId)
{
// season as type and option as its id
var dataString = 'loadType='+ loadType +'&loadId='+ loadId;
// alert(dataString);
$("#"+loadType+"_loader").show();
  $("#"+loadType+"_loader").fadeIn(400).html('Please wait... ');
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "<?php echo base_url() ?>seasons/loadData",
  data: dataString,
  cache: false,
  success: function(result)
  {
    console.log('success');
    console.log(result);
    $("#"+loadType+"_loader").hide();
    $("#"+loadType+"_dropdown").html("<option value='-1'>Select "+loadType+"</option>");  
    $("#"+loadType+"_dropdown").append(result);  
  },
   fail: function(result)
   {
    console.log('Fail');
    console.log(result);

  }
});
```

}

And here is my Controller Function: **Season/loadData**

```
public function loadData()
{
    $session_id = $this->session->userdata('id');
    if (isset($session_id)) 
    {
        $loadType = $_POST['loadType'];
        $loadId   = $_POST['loadId'];
        $HTML="";

        if ($loadType = "season") 
        {
            $result = $this->model_season->getSeasonData($loadType,$loadId);
            if($result->num_rows() > 0)
            {
                // print_r($result->result());
                // die();
                foreach($result->result() as $list)
                {
                    $HTML.="<option value='".$list->season_num_id."'>".$list->season_num."</option>";
                }

            }

            echo $HTML;
        }

        else
        {
            $result = $this->model_season->getEpisodeData($loadType,$loadId);
            // echo $result;

            if($result->num_rows() > 0)
            {

                foreach($result->result() as $list)
                {
                    $HTML.="<option value='".$list->episodes_id."'>".$list->episode."</option>";
                }
            }
            echo $HTML;
        }

    }
    else
    {
        redirect('user_authentication');
    }
}
```

And Here is my Model Class where i'm fetching result from db:

```
function getSeasonData($loadType,$loadId)
{
    $fieldList    ='season_num_id,season_num';
    $table        ='season_num';
    $fieldName    ='seasons_id_fk';
    $orderByField ='season_num';

    $this->db->select($fieldList);
    $this->db->from($table);
    $this->db->where($fieldName, $loadId);
    $this->db->order_by($orderByField, 'asc');
    $query=$this->db->get();
    if ($query) 
    {
        return $query; 
    }

    else
    {
        return FALSE;
    }


}

function getEpisodeData($loadType,$loadId)
{
    $fieldList     ='episodes_id, episode';
    $table         ='episodes';
    $fieldName     ='season_num_id_fk';
    $orderByField  ='episode';  

    $this->db->select($fieldList);
    $this->db->from($table);
    $this->db->where($fieldName, $loadId);
    $this->db->order_by($orderByField, 'asc');
    $query=$this->db->get();

    if ($query->row() > 0) 
    {
        return $query;
    }

    else
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

}
```

First time on selecting **Series** i get options as a result e.g 1,2,3,4
But when i select those numbers to get further episodes it return nothing but its not failing ajax request and its not even printing anything from **Else** condition. Help it please ? If any other file is required do tell me please. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In ajax call use error: instead of fail: to get if any error

```
fail: function(result)
{
    console.log('Fail');
    console.log(result);
    $("#"+loadType+"_loader").hide();
    $("#"+loadType+"_dropdown").html("<option value='-1'>Select "+loadType+"</option>");  
    $("#"+loadType+"_dropdown").append(result);  
},

error: function(result)
{
    console.log(result);
}
```

**Note :**  in Codeigniter if php code have any error then it will return the 500 status in response so ajax success function cant handle this response and give it to error function. but as in the your code you are using fail that's why you are not getting any logs.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback but its not returning 500 response, even doing error call is going to success.